# Problems with centering a figure

Tags: spacing, graphics

I have a problem with centering a figure. At first I have set for 12 pt and the figures were centered. Then I put 10 pt and all the figures shifted to right. How can I solve this problem? 
Here is what I have written:

```
\begin{figure}[htpb] 
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.70]{Figura 5.pdf}
\vspace{-130mm}
\caption{Esempio di domini isospettrali.}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If the graphics ends to be wider than the text width, no centering is possible. Use `width=.9\textwidth` instead of `scale=0.7`. What's the `\vspace` for?

Comment: I used it to place properly the caption.

Comment: Having to back up by 13 centimeters means you have an ill-formed image, with too much white space. Probably adding `trim=0 13cm 0 0` to the options to `\includegraphics` is a better choice; you may have to trim also at the other sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `scale`, unless you know precisely the original dimensions of the graphic object and the text width of your document. Using

```
width=0.9\textwidth
```

will be better.

Using `\vspace` for backing up is not good either. You probably want to trim the excess white space in your image:

```
\includegraphics[trim=0 13cm 0 0,width=0.9\textwidth]{<filename>}
```

may be what you're looking for.